# Regex to find comments starting with either ; or # characters

Tags: regex

I have ini files that have comments in the  but in one ini file the comments start with

```
; Enable the PHP scripting language engine under Apache.
engine = On
; Enable compatibility mode with Zend Engine 1 (PHP 4.x)
zend.ze1_compatibility_mode = Off
; Allow the <? tag.  Otherwise, only <?php and <script> tags are recognized.
```

and the other with

```
# The default storage engine that will be used when create new tables when
default-storage-engine=INNODB

# The maximum amount of concurrent sessions the MySQL server will
# allow. One of these connections will be reserved for a user with
# SUPER privileges to allow the administrator to login even if the
# connection limit has been reached.
max_connections=255
```

currently find the beginning of the first using regex involves using

```
^(;).*$\n
```

I tried to modify this using

```
^[;#].*$\n
```

to find either of the two comments but it did not work what would be the correct regex to find comments of either type?

All of your suggestion where very helpful. The additional thing that I need to do was close the application and then reopen it to see the change take effect.

Comment: the character class `^[;#]` should work. what regex flavour are you using?

Comment: I am using sublime text which uses if I am correct Perl-style regex

Comment: Your don't need `\n` at the end of your regex. `$` is matching the end-of-line.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That should work, however you can try the alteration syntax:

```
^(;|#).*$
```

Answer (score 3):

```
^(;|#).*$\n
```

Seems to work fine here

Answer (score 1):

In some regex flavors, `#` denotes an inline comment (meaning that it comments out part of the regex). If `^(;).*$\n` works but `^[;#].*$\n` doesn't, I would try escaping the `#` with a backslash.

I'd consider ignoring leading whitespace as well:

```
/^\s*[;\#].*?$/m
```

Note the `/m` to activate multiline mode. This (combined with the lazy `.*?`) is what you want to use in order to apply the pattern to each line. I also don't think you want `\n` at the end, as in your pattern; putting `\n` after `$` makes no sense except in multiline mode, where it will essentially do nothing except prevent a match on the final line.

It might help to let us know which regex flavor you're using, and what exactly happened when you tried your version.

Comment: I am using perl-style regex. The syntax highlighter did not pick up the comments as comments.

Comment: @capnhud Can you explain what happened when you tried to use your pattern? Did it cause an error or simply fail to match? Note that syntax highlighters don't always get it right. [Here's a test of this pattern on Rubular](http://rubular.com/r/LWmCxf3IPv).

Comment: ignoring the whitespace and going to multiline mode produces the result of neither comment types are indicated as comments. It had just simply failed to match

Comment: @capnhud - Whether multiline or the lazy `.*?` are needed, and the risk of `#` commenting out part of your regex, are both going to depend on the regex flavor. I tested the pattern above on [RegExr](http://regexr.com?2ukfk) and [Rubular](http://rubular.com/r/LWmCxf3IPv): RegExr required multiline but not necessarily `.*?`, and Rubular required `.*?` but not multiline (Ruby uses multiline by default). RegExr uses the JavaScript regex engine, and Rubular uses Ruby. Your mileage may vary, but without knowing your regex flavor I went with what I knew would work.

Comment: Also, I should explain that the bit about ignoring whitespace at the beginning was meant as an aside. It's not the problem here, but ini/config files like this often have whitespace before their comments, so I'd take that into account if I were you.

Comment: I appreciate your assistance greatly at first I did not know which type of regex was being used until I googled it and discovered it a Perl-like regex flavor. I will keep your suggestions in my regex pad for future use.